# Principal component analysis with missing data

Tags: clustering, pca, multivariate-analysis

For a prospective study of parameters affecting student's success in graduate school I am looking at a population of about 1500 med students. I have performed a cluster analysis (using Gower's universal similarity index and average linking) showing that students fall into 3 main groups (at ~ 0.2), each with several subgroups (at ~ 0.8). Clustering correlates poorly with study success or with any of the other parameters.

Normally, I'd perform a PCA in the hope of uncovering hidden variables that determine clustering. However, about 1/3 of the students fail the course at various time-points, so that there are a lot of missing data. To make matters worse, student performance on various exams (e.g., NBME Step1 and Step2) is only weakly correlated (r^2 ~ 0.3), so "filling" the table with calculated values would be questionable. Unfortunately, standard PCA reacts "poorly" to missing data.

I should add that the parameters are a mix of nominal, binary, ordinal and rational variables.

Comment: I'm not sure of the best method, but one idea is to use an imputation method to fill in the missing values, and then do PCA using the imputed values

Comment: I wonder, "missing" value means a student did not make it until a certain grade? Should that really be considered a missing value? Maybe [survival analysis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_analysis) would be able to make more of your data?

Answer (score 1):

In a similar situation but in different field we used correlation matrix shrinkage by [Ledoit Wolf](http://www.ledoit.net/honey.pdf). The idea's to calculate the pair-wise covariance matrix using all available data. If instead you drop observations where one student's data is missing, there's nothing left of the dataset. So, we use the intersection of data for each pair of items, not for the entire set. Since s correlation matrix can end up being non PSD in this case, we apply the mentioned shrinkage method to it before plugging into PCA

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can poorly implement PCA wrt. missing data, but you can also spend a bit on extra thought on how to handle missing data, and how to estimate covariance in this case. However, PCA may react badly to non-continuous values...
Projecting the data is also more difficult, and you will have to do some kind of missing value imputation then.
But didn't the clustering with Gower's suffer from the same problem, too? How did you solve it there?

By any means, don't expect magic to happen. Your data is very dirty and the systematic missing values may require you to do a rather complex missing value estimation, not just some default library call.

Comment: Gowers universal coefficient is robust towards missing data, that is one of its big advantages (see Sneath & Sokal 1973, pp. 135): for individuals j and k and characters i the S_g = Sum(W_ijk S_ijk) / Sum(W_ijk) with the weight set to 1 for a valid and 0 for an invalid comparison. Thus for a missing datum neither the numerator nor the denominator increase. Of course, S_g is based on fewer characters if either individual has missing data, reducing its relevance. But you fully use the information available.

Comment: You can do the exact same in PCA. Weighted covariance. That is what I hinted at in the beginning, handle missing data in PCA.

Comment: Ah, that would be useful. Is there software available to do this? Perhaps a R package?

Comment: I don't use R, but I am pretty sure R can do this without any packages.

Comment: I finally solved the problem by "last value carried forward" imputation: Calculate the standard deviations from the mean of the last known result and use that to calculate probable outcomes for the missing values. With that imputed data table, I got meaningful results from a PCA.